# What does the values on Vector3 means?

Tags: java, libgdx

This chunk of code rotates a font 180 degrees:

```
Matrix4 mx4Font = new Matrix4();
BitmapFont font;
SpriteBatch spriteFont;

font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/font/agencyFB.fnt");
Gdx.files.internal("data/font/agencyFB.png"), true); //must be set true to be flipped
mx4Font.setToRotation(new Vector3(200, 200, 0), 180); <---------------------
spriteFont.setTransformMatrix(mx4Font);
spriteFont.begin();
font.setColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
font.draw(spriteFont, "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", 100, 110);
spriteFont.end();`
```

I know that is used to identify the axes, but if was just that we could use 0 or 1...

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Matrix4.html#setToRotation-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3-float-), "Sets the matrix to a rotation matrix around the given axis."

Therefore you would be correct in that you could use `mx4Font.setToRotation(new Vector3(1, 1, 0), 180);`
The best way to check this would be to try and see if it works.

Comment: The problem is that when I try to rotate the font, it disapears of the screen, no matter if I use 1 ou 200. In OpenGL this can happen when the rotation center is not the origin. Is there a way to say I want to rotate around origin(x = 0, y = 0)?

Comment: @user3365436 translate to the center, rotate, translate back

Comment: I've just tried to do what you said. But first One question, when applying transformations to matrix does it need to be in the reverse order like OpenGL? I've written this chunk of code:matrix.setToTranslation(-200, -200, 0);
 matrix.setToRotation(new Vector3(1, 1, 0), 90);
 matrix.setToTranslation(200, 200, 0);
    
 batch.setTransformMatrix(matrix);
    
        batch.begin();
       font.draw(batch, "Winner1", 200, 200);
 batch.end();                                                        But it just does not rotate and the position changes to (400, 400).

Comment: Yes, it uses column major order like opengl. Note the method names `setToXXX()`. These set and overrides the previous transforms. So you would have first set it to a translation, then a rotation, then finally another translation of (200,200,0) before you've applied the transformation. Instead use the `translate()` and `rotate()` methods.

Comment: I'm drawing on position (200, 200, 0).So I translate it to the center matrix.translate(-200, -200, 0); then I rotate it around x: matrix.rotate(new Vector3(1, 0, 0), 90); and then I move it to it's original position matrix.translate(200, 200, 0);But this doesn't work, when I apply the rotation the text disapears :(

Comment: Does it render if you don't use any transforms?

Comment: Yes, when i don't use any transforms it renders perfectly, or when i just use translation it renders too but when I try to make a rotation it stop appearing, I guess because I'm doing it wrong and it is taken out of screen. A possible error is the chosen axis of rotation, i want to rotate  horizontal text to vertical text, I need to rotate 90 degrees but around which axis? Thanks

Comment: @user3365436 There appears to be some weird issue with it rendering only half of the text at a time. Drawing it at both -180 and 180 seems to solve this (if you comment out one block you will see the issue). Here is the code I ran to test this: https://gist.github.com/vgonsalv/c40d7ddf0a38b52430b0